# How do I add header data in HttpClient/PostAsync

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, httpclient

using

```
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               { "thing1", "hello" },
               { "thing2", "world" }
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I have not seen an examnle with adding headers, only data values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormUrlEncodedContent class inherits from [HttpContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent), which contains the [Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.headers?view=netframework-4.7.2) property, which you can use to add/remove/set the http headers.

The [Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.headers?view=netframework-4.7.2) property is an instance of [HttpContentHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders), so check that last class' docs to see the available methods and properties you can use to alter the headers you want.

Example:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
content.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "My Value");
content.Headers.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```